# Laravel Lumen, Swagger returns json not the view

Tags: laravel, swagger, swagger-ui, lumen

I installed [SwaggerLume](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume) with the following configurations

```
class ApiController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @OA\Info(
     *      version="3.0",
     *      title="OpenApi Documentation",
     *      description=""
     * )
     *
     * @OA\Server(
     *      url=SWAGGER_LUME_CONST_HOST,
     *      description="API Server"
     * )
     */
     ...
}
```

and

```
<?php

return [
    'api' => [
        'title' => 'Swagger Lume API',
    ],

    'routes' => [
        'api' => '/api/documentation',
        'docs' => '/api/oa',
        'oauth2_callback' => '/api/oauth2-callback',
        'assets' => '/swagger-ui-assets',
        'middleware' => [
            'api' => [],
            'asset' => [],
            'docs' => [],
            'oauth2_callback' => [],
        ],
    ],

    'paths' => [
        'docs' => storage_path('api-docs'),
        'docs_json' => 'api-docs.json',
        'annotations' => base_path('app'),
        'excludes' => [],
//        'base' => env('L5_SWAGGER_BASE_PATH', null),

        /*
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        | Absolute path to directory where to export views
        |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
        */
        'views' => base_path('resources/views/vendor/swagger-lume'),
    ],
    'generate_always' => env('SWAGGER_GENERATE_ALWAYS', false),
    'swagger_version' => env('SWAGGER_VERSION', '3.0'),
    'proxy' => false,

    'additional_config_url' => null,
    'operations_sort' => env('L5_SWAGGER_OPERATIONS_SORT', null),
    'validator_url' => null,
    'constants' => [
        'SWAGGER_LUME_CONST_HOST' => env('SWAGGER_LUME_CONST_HOST', 'http://my-default-host.com'),
    ],
];
```

I should note that I commented

```
//        'base' => env('L5_SWAGGER_BASE_PATH', null),
```

since swagger 3 doesn't support basePath.

and .env

```
SWAGGER_LUME_CONST_HOST=payment.local
L5_SWAGGER_BASE_PATH=payment.local
```

but the result is

[image]

Not the view. I also have the view

[image]

Comment: what url are you browsing when that json is shown? Does it end like ".json"?

Comment: @C4pt4inC4nn4bis no it has not json. I visit  xxx.com/api/oa

Answer (score 0):

I posted a workaround [here](https://github.com/DarkaOnLine/SwaggerLume/issues/79#issuecomment-1009508961) that works for me.

Comment: Please, post answer here if possible, because at some point of time your link would be broken. So avoid provide answers with links to external sources

Comment: You can  run these commands:
`mkdir public/swagger-ui-assets`  and  
`cp vendor/swagger-api/swagger-ui/dist/* public/swagger-ui-assets
`  
After that, change the line `<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{{ swagger_lume_asset('swagger-ui.css') }}" >` in resources/views/vendor/swagger-lume/index.blade.php to
`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://unpkg.com/swagger-ui-dist@3/swagger-ui.css">`